# Dropbox in Ventura: how to make all Dropbox folder available offline (downloaded to disk) recursively?

Tags: recursion, directory, dropbox, offline

Basically that: in the new roll-out of Dropbox, where it has been moved to ~/Library/CloudStorage, Dropbox content is by default not available offline, only on-cloud (online).

I seem to have to click on every folder to be able to make it available offline.
Tried to do it on parent folders, but did not work.

Any ideas if this is possible so one doesn't have to click on thousands of folders (...)?

Comment: I believe this is a question better asked on "Ask Different": https://apple.stackexchange.com. Likewise, this is also a good question for Dropbox's official support channels. If they haven't implemented this, user questions and feedback would be critical to prioritizing this change.